# Como definir charset UTF8?

Tags: sql, firebird

Possuo uma base de dados que foi criada usando o Firebird 1.0, nesta época não existia o charset UTF8 disponível, apenas a partir da versão 2.0 foi ter essa possibilidade, então deixamos o charset none.

### Dúvidas:

1° Como posso definir charset UTF8? lembrando que o charset é setado em todas as colunas.

2° Redefinir essa códificação pode danificar os dados existentes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para definir o charset no firebird deve ser na criação do database

```
CREATE DATABASE <database> 
  USER <username> 
  PASSWORD <password> 
  PAGE_SIZE <pagesize> 
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET <charset>
```

Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
CREATE DATABASE localhost:meter
  USER SYSDBA
  PASSWORD masterkey
  PAGE_SIZE 4096
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

Para alterar um charset já existente

```
ALTER CHARACTER SET charset SET DEFAULT COLLATION collation
```

Veja o exemplo:

```
alter character set utf8 set default collation unicode_ci_ai
```

Se você usar `SET DEFAULT COLLATION` sobre o conjunto de caracteres padrão do banco de dados, você tem efetivamente definido o agrupamento padrão para o banco de dados.
Se você usar `SET DEFAULT COLLATION` no conjunto de caracteres de conexão, as constantes string será interpretado de acordo com o novo agrupamento padrão. Na maioria das situações, isso não fará diferença, mas as comparações podem ter outro resultado se o agrupamento muda.